# ListView.Builder only showing inside Container

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a ListView.builder inside a Card that is part of a Column that I need it's height to be dyanmic. Currently the only solution I can get to actually display anything is to place the ListView inside a Container with a specified height. If I wrap the builder in anything else such as Expanded, the widget does not render on the screen. Here is my current code;

```
Card(
          elevation: 6,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                            '${viewModel.property.propC}',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                            '${dateFormat.format(viewModel.property.propB)}',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                            '${timeFormat.format(viewModel.property.propA)}',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                      height: 200, child: buildList(context)),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: HexColor("#52cfd2"), elevation: 5),
                        onPressed: () {
                          return null;
                        },
                        child: Text('Press Me',
                            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

List widget;

```
  Widget buildCustomerCarList(context) {
return ListView.builder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
  itemCount: viewModel.property.propertyD.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('First name: ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              Text(
                  viewModel
                      .propA.property[index].firstname,
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 18))
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Last name: ',
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              Text(
                  viewModel
                      .propA.property[index].lastname
                      .toString(),
                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 18))
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

}

The desired end result is to have the list automatically take up the space it requires so the ElevatedButton is always pinned to the bottom of the list rather than needing to explicitly specify the size of the Container to hold the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListView` by default tries to fill all available space. Looks like the height constraint it receives is unbounded (infinite) which causes the problem. To prevent `ListView` from taking too much space, add a property to `ListView` called `shrinkWrap` and set it to true. This makes it so that `ListView` gets as big as it's content (children).

For more in-depth explanation and guide on contraints visit these links:

- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints
- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: So remove the container wrapping the ListView and set shrinkWrap to true?

Comment: The only place `ListView` appears in your question is inside of `buildCustomerCarList` which isn't used in the other snippet, so I can't really tell. I'd start by adding `shrinkWrap` property and if it doesn't work, update the snippets and let me know.

Comment: Ah sorry I must have accidentally removed the line. `buildCustomerCarList` should be part of the Column placed within the Card

Comment: Yeah so the way it works is Column gives unbounded (infinite) height to its children. Just slap `ListView` with `shrinkWrap: true` and it should work.

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks for the help man. I didn't know Column behaved that way, TIL!